# Need to add image to existing xls file in rails 2?

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, ruby-on-rails-2

I am reading .xls file through spreadsheet gem and i can successfully update the content, but unable to add image to xls file , please provide any solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there's nothing out there that can do what you want short of actually automating Excel, which you can do from Ruby using WIN32OLE http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html.

In order to do that, however, you'll have to be running Rails on Windows with Excel installed. You'll also probably only be able to process one document at a time per server (either physical or virtualized).

If your app is not hosted on Windows (I presume it isn't), you could write a separate application to do the processing and call out to it as a service from your main application. You'd still have to host that on Windows somewhere though.